# Passing data between fragments for signup

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am singing up a user in 2 fragments in android. First fragment will have personal information and second fragment will contain educational information. I am using fragments inside a viewpager. I want to store the whole data in student object. How do I pass student object from first fragment to second fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your first fragment

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("tag", user);
FragmentTwo frag =new FragmentTwo ();
frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

in your second fragment

```
User user = (User) getArguments().getSerializable("tag");
```

Comment: Ok. So correct me if I got it wrong. In first fragment I save name, username, email, password in student object and then pass that object to fragment 2 and save the remaining info in that object. Is this how it's gonna work?

Comment: yes, your User class must impliments Serialisable interface

Comment: Thanks so much. I got it. Another I want to do is to switch between fragment s on button click i.e. on fragment one I have a next button which will take me to second fragment. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As per Android Developer website All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.
For more details you can look up http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html